# MFMailComposeViewController navigationBar color is not perfectly matching

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have already tried almost all exist solution for changing the `navigationBar` color of my `MFMailComposeViewController`, but it is not showing exact color.

This is my `viewController` navigation bar color:

[image]

And after customizing all solution the closest one is this:

[image]

What is the thing I am missing here in my code? please take have a look.

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mc.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[mc setSubject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V%@ Support", version]];
[mc setMessageBody:supportText isHTML:NO];
[mc setToRecipients:@[@"ring@ringid.com"]];
[self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

I tried with:

```
mc.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
[mc.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor myColor]];
mc.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor myColor];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nav-bar_6_plus.png"];
[mc.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

But no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You must be having an issue with the translucency of the bar. You should try setting the mc.navigationBar.translucent to YES or NO (depends upon how you want it to look).

Comment: Sorry for let mention. Yeah, I always set mc.navigationBar.translucent to NO. But the color is not showing the same. :(

Comment: I'm having this same problem. I set the color before it's instantiated and it's making the navigation bar color lighter than it should be..

Comment: I have the same problem, does any buddy has the solution ?

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:-

In Swift 3.0

```
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
```

Setting the appearance of the `UINavigationBar` solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe its because the bar is transparent if you call

`[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];`

that should fix it.

Comment: Yes. I check it with `mc.navigationBar.translucent = NO;`
Please see the update post. But not getting the same color.